# Python - take the time difference from the first date in a column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe

Given the date column, I want to create another column diff that count how many days apart from the first date.

```
date                    diff
2011-01-01 00:00:10      0
2011-01-01 00:00:11      0.000011 days
2011-02-01 00:00:11      30.000011 days 
2013-02-01 00:00:11      395.000011 days
2014-02-01 00:00:11      760.000011 days
```

Dates are in datetime. What I tried so far:

```
df = df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True)
df.set_index('date', inplace = True)
first = df.index[0]
df['diff'] = (first - df.index.shift()).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
df['diff'] = df.date - df.date.min()

df
                 date               diff
0 2011-01-01 00:00:10    0 days 00:00:00
1 2011-01-01 00:00:11    0 days 00:00:01
2 2011-02-01 00:00:11   31 days 00:00:01
3 2013-02-01 00:00:11  762 days 00:00:01
4 2014-02-01 00:00:11 1127 days 00:00:01
```

Comment: @nimrodz `min()` may fail if there are other dates less than the first date. It's better to just use `df.date - df.date[0]`

Comment: @pygo df example added

Comment: @SaiKumar  `min()` should work here because `df.date[0]` is the min date due to values sorting `df.sort_values(['date'], ascending=True)`

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I'd do to get days as float number values:

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.date) # make sure we are working with dates and not strings
df["diff"] = (dates - dates[0]).apply(lambda x: x.total_seconds() / 86400))
```

The resulting `df`:

```
                  date         diff
0  2011-01-01 00:00:10     0.000000
1  2011-01-01 00:00:11     0.000012
2  2011-02-01 00:00:11    31.000012
3  2013-02-01 00:00:11   762.000012
4  2014-02-01 00:00:11  1127.000012
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach without setting a new index

Raw dataframe

```
df
                 date        diff
0 2011-01-01 00:00:10    0.000000
1 2011-01-01 00:00:11    0.000011
2 2011-02-01 00:00:11   30.000011
3 2013-02-01 00:00:11  395.000011
4 2014-02-01 00:00:11  760.000011
```

Possible answer

```
df['diff_new'] = df['date'] - df.loc[0,'date']

                 date        diff           diff_new
0 2011-01-01 00:00:10    0.000000    0 days 00:00:00
1 2011-01-01 00:00:11    0.000011    0 days 00:00:01
2 2011-02-01 00:00:11   30.000011   31 days 00:00:01
3 2013-02-01 00:00:11  395.000011  762 days 00:00:01
4 2014-02-01 00:00:11  760.000011 1127 days 00:00:01
```

BTW, I get different date differences that you show in the raw data for the 3rd row. You can compare manually with [this online tool to calculate date differences in days](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?m1=02&d1=01&y1=2013&m2=02&d2=01&y2=2014).

Comment: My first answer here was wrong since it gave the difference between successive rows. I have updated this. Apologies for the misunderstanding. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you try..

```
>>> df
                  date
0  2011-01-01 00:00:10
1  2011-01-01 00:00:11
2  2011-02-01 00:00:11
3  2013-02-01 00:00:11
4  2014-02-01 00:00:11
```

First convert them to timestamps, so data can be framed correctly, Once converted, simply difference the DataFrame:

```
>>> df2 = df.apply(lambda x: [pd.Timestamp(ts) for ts in x])
>>> df['diff']  = (df2 - df2.shift()).fillna(0)
>>> df
                  date              diff
0  2011-01-01 00:00:10   0 days 00:00:00
1  2011-01-01 00:00:11   0 days 00:00:01
2  2011-02-01 00:00:11  31 days 00:00:00
3  2013-02-01 00:00:11 731 days 00:00:00
4  2014-02-01 00:00:11 365 days 00:00:00
```