# how to normalize date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas column of type date which ranges from 2015-01-01 to 2019-01-01 and I want to create a new column which can normalize my values to single digit

I have a pandas column like below

```
A

2015-01-01
2015-02-01
2015-03-01
...
...
2019-12-01
```

and I want a new column like below

```
A                   B

2015-01-01          0
2015-02-01          1
2015-03-01          2
2015-05-01.         4
...
2019-11-01.         46
2019-12-01          47
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - take the time difference from the first date in a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53000926/python-take-the-time-difference-from-the-first-date-in-a-column)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.asfreq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) with `DatetimeIndex` for all values, then crate range column by [`DataFrame.assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) and last use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df.set_index('A').asfreq('MS').assign(new=lambda x: np.arange(len(x)))['new']
df['B'] = df['A'].map(s) 
print (df)
           A   B
0 2015-01-01   0
1 2015-02-01   1
2 2015-03-01   2
3 2019-12-01  59
```

**Detail**:

```
print (s)
A
2015-01-01     0
2015-02-01     1
2015-03-01     2
2015-04-01     3
2015-05-01     4
2015-06-01     5
2015-07-01     6
...
...
...
2019-06-01    53
2019-07-01    54
2019-08-01    55
2019-09-01    56
2019-10-01    57
2019-11-01    58
2019-12-01    59
Freq: MS, Name: new, dtype: int32
```

Comment: Thank you, this should work but lets say there is a date missing from my field 2015-03-01 and for next date 2015-04-01 I want value to be assigned 4 instead of 3

Answer (score 1):

We can using `resample`

```
df1=df.copy()
df.index=df.A
s=df.resample('MS').count()
df1['B']=df1.A.map(pd.Series(np.arange(len(s)),index=s.index))
df1
           A   B
0 2015-01-01   0
1 2015-02-01   1
2 2015-03-01   2
3 2019-12-01  59
```

Comment: @jezrael it is work , and we just need to adding some filter ,make sure the new df only keep the original date :-)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `A` is a datetime column

```
df['A'] = pd.to_datetime(df['A'])
```

Subtract the start date from every subsequent date.

```
start = df['A'].sort_values('A').iloc[0, 0]
df'B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: x - start).dt.days
```